# Custom function by date for related tables

Tags: expression, relationship, forecasting, spotfire, crosstab

*"In a crosstab, latest month where Actuals has any data, show Actuals data for that and all previous months. Future months, show Forecast data."*

.

I have two tables- Forecasts and Actuals- and the common columns between them are Team, Month, Value.

I'd like to show the data in a crosstab with Month as columns and Team as rows. I'm trying to write an expression to do this in the crosstab: The most recent month where Actuals has any data, I'd like to show Actuals data for that and all previous months, for all teams. For following months, I'd like to show Forecast data.

Any suggestions about how to go about this would be appreciated. I'm still piecing together my knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a third table from a transformations:

1. Create Third table from - Pivot date on  Team & Month (to ensure every possible combination) from first table
2. Add Rows from transforming the second table (pivot on  Team & Month)
3. Join the two original tables to your newly created table (has every possible combination of Team & Month) so that both your data sets are now in one table.
4. Now use the third table in your cross table.
5. If you try using column matching instead of the above method only dates from the main table will show as the dates are matched and ones missing from the other will not display.